# Rotating a marker on a map, uses a UIImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'd like to rotate an instance of the class RMMarker on the map of my iPhone app, to the current bearing the person is heading. The RMMarker uses a UIImage , and it's a little blue arrow.

If RMMarkers used a UIImageView, rotating wouldbe a piece of cake, because I would use CGAffineTransformMakeRotation. But RMMarker's use UIIMages, so I can't use this method.

Am I overlooking a simple way of solving this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to rotate the underlying CGImage with this code: http://blog.coriolis.ch/2009/09/04/arbitrary-rotation-of-a-cgimage/